# in operator not working as I expect with a list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm pulling my hair out with a sample statement.  My line of code is this.

```
Test2 = selector2.xpath('string(//div[@class="js-shipping-slide-panel shipping-slide-panel-section product-buying-table-row-alt"])').extract()
print "Test2", Test2
```

I get an output of:

```
Test2 [u'    Shipping not available     \n      Shipping   This item is not      available for shipping.    \n']
```

That's perfect.  So here's my sample If Statement I am trying

```
if "shipping" in Test2:
    print "Found it"
else:
    print "It's Not There"
```

and I am getting a result of It's not there.  I even copied the output and hardcoded Test2 to be

```
Test2 = "u'    Shipping not available     \n      Shipping   This item is not      available for shipping.    \n'"
```

and the ran the same if statement and it worked, giving me a result of "Found it".  What am I missing here?  Thanks.

Comment: Also, I want to use Test2.lower and say if "shipping not available" then....blah... with that try to match all 3 words in any order or will it have to be an exact match in the exact order?  Thanks.

Comment: Your first example output is a string in a list, your hardcoded output is just the string. To check the string in your example output, you would need to do: `if "shipping" in Test2[0]:` to check within the string rather than checking if the string 'shipping' is in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in your output that `Test2` is not a string.  It is a list containing a string.  Try `if "shipping" in Test2[0]`.  (You should also think about what you want to do if your xpath query returns multiple results.)

Comment: You guys are awesome.  I love it when it's something simple....now I have to wait 11 minutes to accept the answer.  Any thoughts on the second question while I am waiting?

Comment: Thoughts on what do do if xpath returns multiple results? Open another question on StackOverflow after thinking about it and trying to handle it if you still have a question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a singleton `list`. This means that you have to check whether `'shipping'` is in the first element of that `list`.

```
if "shipping" in Test2[0]:
```

Your other test is checking whether the entire string, *including extra surrounding quotes that aren't actually part of the original string*, is in the `list`, which, of course, it isn't. The `list` you're checking contains a string that doesn't contain surrounding quotes:

```
"u'    Shipping not available     \n      Shipping   This item is not      available for shipping.    \n'"
```

is not

```
u'    Shipping not available     \n      Shipping   This item is not      available for shipping.    \n'
```

The first character of the former string is the letter `u`. The first character of the latter string is a space character, . You would have to send the former string to a parser like `ast.literal_eval()` to produce the latter string (but the right thing to do is to hard-code your test string *correctly*, taking into account Python syntax).